# Dados CPF em uma Struct em C

Tags: c, struct

Olá. Estou com um problema para ler dados de um CPF. Testei utilizar int, long int ou mesmo um vetor de char[12]. Com o char consigo manter os CPF's que contem '0' no inicio, e com o int ou long int não retorna correto devido ao tamanho. Preciso fazer uma ordenação com estes dados também e a ordem não fica correta também. Acredito que seja devido ao tipo de dado que fica incorreto.

Comment: Com numéricos bastaria você acrescentar os zeros à esquerda ao exibir. Com char gasta mais espaço do que precisa, mas armazena de maneira bem previsivel (e nao teria problema em ordenar da esquerda pra direita). No meio de campo você teria o BCD, mas aí ja demandaria algumas funções mais específicas. Seria legal dar detalhes do problema em específico, e o objetivo final do que está fazendo (geralmente o foco no objetivo é melhor do que o foco na atual tentativa).

Answer (score 4):

Tem várias formas de você guardar um cpf na memória/banco de dados.

1. **String:** use um `char[12]`, ou então um `char[11]` já que você sabe o tamanho. Se lembre de nunca usar operações que esperam uma string com terminador nulo, como `strcpy`. Use `memcpy` ou mesmo `strncpy` no lugar.
2. **Array:** guarde cada dígito em uma array. Pode ser `uint8_t[11]`. É similar a usar a opção de string. Mas você precisará usar um loop para fazer qualquer operação com os dígitos.
3. **Inteiro:** utilize um único `uint64_t`. É a forma mais simples de operar se você não precisa dos dígitos separados. Para exibir na tela utilize: `print("cpf: %011"PRIu64".", cpf);` Explicando o formato: um inteiro `uint64_t` com 11 dígitos de tamanho, preenchendo o espaço faltante com `0`. A macro `PRIu64` denota a string usada no `printf`. Para o `scanf` pode usar assim: `scanf("%"SCNu64, &cpf);`

Qualquer uma das três serve e sem dúvida existem mais. Escolha a que melhor se adapta ao seu caso específico.

Comment: Como ficaria um scanf deste uint64_t? E qual a biblioteca correspondente a esta função?

Answer (score 2):

Olá, o problema principal de armazenar número com zero inicio começa quando o número possui mais de 7 dígitos, como é o caso do CPF. O compilador acredita que quando um número possui mais de 7 dígitos e começa com zero que ele é da base 8. Causando alguns problemas para a gente. A melhor opção é armazenar os números neste caso como uma string.

Por exemplo, para verificar se a quantidade de números está correta poderíamos fazer algo como:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int checkCPF(char* cpf) {
        printf("CPF como string: %s \n", cpf);
        printf("Números do CPF: %lu \n", strlen(cpf));
        if(strlen(cpf)==11) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
}


int main() {
        char* cpfA = "18315228889";
        char* cpfB = "0031522888";

        checkCPF(cpfA);
        checkCPF(cpfB);

        return 0;
}
```

Porém isso não é muito pratico se você for trabalhar com os números em si, efetuar algum tipo de validação ou pegar somente uma parte do número, neste caso podemos utilizar uma estrutura de CPF, você pode implementar sua estrutura da forma que desejar, por exemplo:

```
typedef struct _CPF{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
    unsigned int c;
    unsigned int verificador;
} CPF;
```

É uma estrutura bem simples, e você pode trabalhar com os números de forma isolada.
Para conseguir o CPF completo como um `long int` você pode utilizar uma função como:

```
long int getCPFCompleto(CPF cpf) {
    long int cpfCompleto = 0;
    char buffer[12];
    char* fixEnd;
    sprintf(buffer, "%d%d%d%d", cpf.a, cpf.b, cpf.c, cpf.verificador);
    cpfCompleto = strtol (buffer,&fixEnd,10);
    return cpfCompleto;
}
```

Claro, caso o CPF possuir o primeiro número 0 em qualquer um dos elementos isso pode causar problemas então é melhor retornar o valor como uma string novamente.

A lógica está completa. Vou postar somente o código completo comentado e espero que possa te auxiliar em algo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc

// Nossa estrutura básica para armazenar o CPF
typedef struct _CPF{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
    unsigned int c;
    unsigned int verificador;
} CPF;


// Retorna o CPF completo
// É possivel informar se queremos o número formatado ou não
void getCPFCompleto(char* buffer, CPF cpf, int formatado) {
    long int cpfCompleto = 0;

    // Aqui está um ponto fundamental
    // Perceba que informmos %03d informando que esperamos 3 dígitios
    // Caso ele conter menos que 3 digitos ele adiciona zero a esquerda.
    // Execeto no número verificado com 2 dígitos
    if(formatado)
        sprintf(buffer, "%03d.%03d.%03d-%02d", cpf.a, cpf.b, cpf.c, cpf.verificador);
    else
        sprintf(buffer, "%03d%03d%03d%02d", cpf.a, cpf.b, cpf.c, cpf.verificador);
}

// Populamos nossa variavel CPF
void populateCPF(CPF* cpf, char* cpfString, int formatado) {
    if(formatado)
        sscanf(cpfString, "%03u.%03u.%03u-%02u", &cpf->a, &cpf->b, &cpf->c, &cpf->verificador);
    else
        sscanf(cpfString, "%03d%03d%03d%02d", &cpf->a, &cpf->b, &cpf->c, &cpf->verificador);
}



int main() {
    CPF mCPF;
    char* cpfCompleto;

    // Alocamos 15 caso o valor retornado possuir formatação
    cpfCompleto = (char*) malloc(15*sizeof(char));

    // Passamos nossa o ponteiro para nossa variavel CPF
    // O CPF para ser formatado como string
    // E se o número é formatado ou não
    populateCPF(&mCPF, "08315228802", 0);

    // Podemos imprimir os elementos de forma unitaria
    printf("CPF A: %03d\n", mCPF.a);
    printf("CPF B: %03d\n", mCPF.b);
    printf("CPF C: %03d\n", mCPF.c);
    printf("CPF Verificador: %02d\n", mCPF.verificador);


    // Podemos imprimir o número completo utilizando a função
    // getCPFCompleto
    // Informamos um ponteiro para char a variavel com o CPF
    // e se queremos formatada ou não

    getCPFCompleto(cpfCompleto, mCPF, 0);
    printf("O número do CPF completo é: %s \n", cpfCompleto);


    // Vamos liberar a memoria do buffer
    free(cpfCompleto);

    return 0;
};
```